# How to use schemas in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I would like to use PostgreSQL schemas with Django, how can I do this?

Comment: I am just starting with Django and it strikes me that such basic feature is not yet natively supported. Especially when there is [a 7 year old feature request](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6148) open.

Comment: Could you please unmark the [answer by kmpm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1912906/2066215) as accepted? It is no longer functional.

Comment: I am no longer using Django frequently, so If there is a good answer for this question please let me now so I could mark as answered the best one.

Comment: I stopped using Django myself. IMHO you should not accept any of the answers, since none solves this issue. The best you can do is changing the SEARCH_PATH, but it only works if you are using a single schema.

Answer (score 39):

Maybe this will help.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=your_schema'
        },
        'NAME': 'your_name',
        'USER': 'your_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'your_password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

I get the answer from the following link:
http://blog.amvtek.com/posts/2014/Jun/13/accessing-multiple-postgres-schemas-from-django/

Answer (score 36):

I've been using:

```
db_table = '"schema"."tablename"'
```

in the past without realising that only work for read-only operation. When you try to add new record it would fail because the sequence would be something like "schema.tablename"_column_id_seq.

```
db_table = 'schema\".\"tablename'
```

does work so far. Thanks.

Comment: I don't use PostgreSQL, but this is how I make it work in SQL Server too.

Comment: Any trick for creating the schema automatically in syncdb before creating tables? Necessary for running test suites.

Comment: Warning, using the naming works but will fail for creating indexes if you use syncdb or migrate

Comment: Where exactly do you introduce that instruction?

Comment: Need to also remember that table and schema names are case sensitive in postgres, got me with all caps.

Comment: @cethegeek, how did you get this working for SQL Server? I used `db_table = 'myschema\".\"mytable'`, and django still created the model as `dbo.myschema.mytable`.

Comment: @CameronTaylor I don't think I ever used Django to create the tables (syncdb). I only used this to access the tables after they were manually created in the database.

Answer (score 11):

It's a bit more complicated than tricky escaping. Have a look at Ticket [#6148](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6148) in Django for perhaps a solution or at least a patch. It makes some minor changes deep in the django.db core but it will hopefully be officially included in django.
After that it's just a matter of saying

```
db_schema = 'whatever_schema'
```

in the Meta class or for a global change set

```
DATABASE_SCHEMA = 'default_schema_name'
```

in settings.py

**UPDATE: 2015-01-08**

The corresponding issue in django has been open for 7 years and the patch there will not work any more.
The correct answer to this should be...

At the moment you can't use postgreSQL schemas in django out of the box.

Comment: Thats because the patch/fix is not implemented yet.

Comment: This is still not functional in Django 1.6.1. Why is this answer marked as accepted? It is even doubtful it classifies as one...

Comment: the ticket #6148 had a patch that never was included and probably never will be. It have been open for 7 years as of writing.

Comment: I probably accepted this answer because back in 2009 it worked. Should I remove the accepted mark?

Comment: The correct answer is in there though, after my update at least. You don't use schemas in django.

Comment: I think this is out of date again: https://www.amvtek.com/blog/posts/2014/Jun/13/accessing-multiple-postgres-schemas-from-django/ seems to work just fine.

Comment: This is needed when using Oracle, and db_schema isnt allowed. Is there another way rather than escaping?

Answer (score 11):

As mentioned in the following ticket:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6148, we could set `search_path` for the django user.

One way to achieve this is to set `search_path` via `psql` client, like

```
ALTER USER my_user SET SEARCH_PATH TO path;
```

The other way is to modify the django app, so that if we rebuild the database, django won't spit all the tables in `public` schema.

To achieve this, you could override the `DatabaseWrapper` defined in [`django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.base`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/86f4459f9e3c035ec96578617605e93234bf2700/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py)

1. Create the following directory:

   ```
   app/pg/
   ├── __init__.py
   └── base.py
   ```
2. Here's the content of `base.py`

   ```
   from django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2.base import DatabaseWrapper

   class DatabaseWrapper(DatabaseWrapper):
       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(DatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       def _cursor(self):
           cursor = super(DatabaseWrapper, self)._cursor()
           cursor.execute('SET search_path = path')
           return cursor
   ```
3. In `settings.py`, add the following database configuration:

   ```
   DATABASES = {
       'default': {
           'ENGINE': 'app.pg',
           'NAME': 'db',
           'USER': 'user',
           'PASSWORD': '',
           'HOST': '',
           'PORT': '',
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This looks like the only valid solution in this thread, however laborious. But how would it work with several "apps"?

Comment: @Luís de Sousa I don't see any problems with several "apps". We have been using this method to deal with the lack of schema support in production for more than 1 years without any problems.

Comment: Minguy, I do not see problems myself, I am just asking how to do it. I am presently on chapter 5 of the Django book.

Comment: There is [a question on this later issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497235/django-schemas-postgresql#comment48690281_4497235), presently closed for unknown reasons. It is very common to find multiple schemas in systems developed on Oracle or Postgres that in Django would correspond to different applications.

Answer (score 7):

I just developed a package for this problem: https://github.com/ryannjohnson/django-schemas.

After some configuration, you can simply call `set_db()` on your models:

```
model_cls = UserModel.set_db(db='db_alias', schema='schema_name')
user_on_schema = model_cls.objects.get(pk=1)
```

The package uses techniques described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1628855/5307109 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/18391525/5307109, then wraps them for use with Django models.

Answer (score 3):

I've had some success just saying

```
db_table = 'schema\".\"tablename'
```

in the Meta class, but that's really ugly. And I've only used it in limited scenarios - it may well break if you try something complicated. And as said earlier, it's not really supported...

Comment: It is indeed ugly, as this way you have to manage table names yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There is no explicit Django support for postgreSQL schemas.

> When using Django (0.95), we had to add a search_path to the Django database connector for PostgreSQL, because Django didn't support specifying the schema that the tables managed by the ORM used.

Taken from:

http://nxsy.org/using-postgresql-schemas-with-sqlalchemy-and-elixir

The general response is to use SQLAlchemy to construct the SQL properly.

Oh, and here's another link with some suggestions about what you can do with the Django base, extending it to try to support your scheme:

http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=662901

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is a rather old question, but a different solution is to alter the SEARCH_PATH.

### Example

Lets say you have three tables.

1. `schema1.table_name_a`
2. `schema2.table_name_b`
3. `table_name_c`

You could run the command:

```
SET SEARCH_PATH to public,schema1,schema2;
```

And refer to the tables by their table names only in django.

See [5.7.3. The Schema Search Path](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-schemas.html)

Comment: This only works if you manage the database manually. If you use `syncdb` with this set up you will end up with all your tables in the `public` schema.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL server database:

```
db_table = "[your_schema].[your_table]"
```

Answer (score -1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from my_app.my_views import ClientViewSet

router = DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)
router.register(r'', ClientViewSet, base_name='clients')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```