# Django Schemas Postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

For a few days i'm trying to get the following right for Django i.c.w. Postgres:

I like to have one database with multiple schemas.
There are 2 kinds of schemas:

- app
- site

The app schema can be used by all the sites and the site schemas are only visible for a specific database user.

For example:
(Sites, every site has a different schema)

- site1
- site2
- site3

(Apps, every app has a different schemas *or* can be placed within one schema):

- App
- **App1**
- **App2**

*or*

- app1
- app2

Is there currently a way to achieve this with Django?

Comment: I did find out how to achieve to above without multipleusers.I can create the different schemas, and from database point of view i also can set permission to the schemas.But then one thing is still be open.In the app schemas, there'll be content that depends on sites. I only can think of keeping the data seperate is to use the sites app from Django. Than the data will be referenced to the correct user. The reason i don't want to have for each app a different table in each sites schema is that if there are changes in the database structure, i have to go over all the schemas to alter the tables.

Comment: Yes, I am sure this can be done.  But design of this area is a rather big field.  Would you mind either posting a clarification or a descrioption of what you did?  Otherwise I am not sure there is enough info to provide a reasonably scoped answer.

Comment: This is a common issue when migrating legacy databases and/or applications composed of several schemas to Django. Since Django is "blind" to schemas it would be interesting to know how folk have dealt with this issue in the past. This question should not be closed.