# Different schemas containing same tables names

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm finding myself with a django project handling two distinct classes mapped on a similar table name:

```
class BarA(models.Model):
[...]
class Meta:
    db_table = 'bar' # doesn't specify any schema

class BarB(models.Model):
[...]
class Meta:
    db_table = u'foo"."bar'
```

The project is using a database containing two schemas: `public` and `foo`.

The way this application is templated and deployed makes things even more confusing: on some servers, django connects to database with the user "John", not member of any role, but on other servers it connects with user "Eric", member of a `foo` role.

Two questions here:

1. If [django's meta class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/) doesn't mention any specific schema, **how does Postgres decide which table it will work with** ?  So far, it appears that user Eric will always hit the `foo.bar` table, and never the `public.bar` one, regardless of the called class.
   With user "John", I'm only using `BarA` class and it properly hits `public.bar`.
2. Django doesn't seem to handle schemas; is [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1628855/1030960) considered as a good practice for that kind of case (please note that I cannot rename the existing tables)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In postgres [`search_path` variable](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html) set the priority for choosing the schema for the table:

> **search_path (string)**
>   This variable specifies the order in which
>   schemas are searched when an object (table, data type, function, etc.)
>   is referenced by a simple name with no schema specified. When there
>   are objects of identical names in different schemas, the one found
>   first in the search path is used.
>   [...]
>   The current effective value of the search path can be examined via the SQL function current_schemas.

A quick way to do so:

```
SELECT current_schemas(True);
```

You can find details on how to manage `search_path` in section 5.7.3. of this article: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html