# How do I change the default schema to custom_schema in postgres from django setting file?

Tags: django, postgresql

Please help me to change the default schema from public to custom_schema. Also I am using the tenant to create the multiple tenants for the same base custom_schema tables.

Comment: You should check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819748/django-and-postgresql-schemas. It can be useful for your question

Comment: Check this answer [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28452103/1079086)

Comment: Thank for the help but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to use only one schema, it is enough that add options to db configuration in settings.py. You should create a new schema called 'custom_schema' before migration.

```
DATABASES = {

'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'options': '-c search_path=custom_schema'
    },
    'NAME': 'name',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
   }
}
```

If you want to use more than one schema, add a second db configuration to the db configuration with only the schema name different. Then write a router to decide which db will work in which situations.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/